# ZSH function to edit a file based on an input at the cli

Tags: zsh, alias, function, oh-my-zsh

I need to set up a function in zsh that would edit a different file based on some input at the command line.

I want to simplify my aliases so I don't have multiple aliases to do the same thing but with a slight variation. I am specifically trying to set up a function to open in my editor different versions of the php.ini file (for php 5.4, 5.5, 5.6 and 7.0)

Right now, I have defined the following aliases:

```
alias editphpini54="subl /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/php.ini"
alias editphpini55="subl /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini"
alias editphpini56="subl /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini"
alias editphpini70="subl /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini"
```

What I would like to do is set up a function called `editphpini` and then input a variable (version number) and have it intelligently open up the right file. This could then be future-proof as well, as long as the basic path remains the same.

So, what I want to do be able to type in

`editphpini 54`

And have the function parse that command and load the `php.ini` file located in `/usr/local/etc/php/5.4/php.ini`

Using the above example, I would then be able to substitute `55` `56` or `70` at the end of the command and that would issue the relevant command.

In my thoughts, the function would take the `XX` version number, insert it into the command `subl /usr/local/etc/php/X.X/php.ini` using the `XX` to define the version number.

Honestly, I have tried multiple things, and nothing seems to work, so rather than just list all my failed attempts, I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thank you,

Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function editphpini() {
    local version=$( echo $1 | sed 's/^\(.\)/\1./' )

    subl /usr/local/etc/php/${version}/php.ini
}
```

usage:

```
% editphpini 54
```

Comment: OK...that seems simple enough...just one question...I want to input the version number without the dot-notation as in `55` but the path has the version with a dot as in `5.5`

Comment: I would add that function to your `~/.zshrc` now and just get this simple version working first. then - if that works - start looking at parameter expansion to handle the dot.

Comment: That works...as per the usage `X.X`. Now, how to expand the parameter to exclude the `.`

Comment: I will mark the answer correct (when it lets me in 4 minutes), and will vote it up when the `.` is gone :)

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you very much @the_velour_fog

Comment: Explanation of @the_velour_fog's `sed` code: replace the first number with the same number and then add the dot. Do nothing with the second number, i.e. leave it as is after the dot.

Answer (score 3):

```
editphpini() subl /usr/local/etc/php/${1[1]}.${1[2,-1]}/php.ini
```

`${1[1]}.${1[2,-1]}` is one of the many ways to transform `xyz` into `x.yz`. Other approaches could be: `${1[1]}.${1#?}`, or `${1/(#m)?/$MATCH.}` or `${(j:.:)${(s::)1}}` (for `x.y.z`)

Comment: nice, I wondered why you didn't mention `${1:0:1}.${1:1:1}` which also seems to work with zsh , I'm guessing because you prefer the array subscript notation?

Comment: @the_velour_fog, yes, that syntax was only added recently for compatibility with ksh93/bash. It clashes with history modifiers and the ${var:-1} syntax so I don't like it much (not to mention the out of character 0-based index).